# call ioctl system call using jna

Tags: java, linux, jna, ioctl

If I want to call the ioctl() system call in Linux using JNA,
which library should I load?

In other words: I already have the following code:

```
public class SystemCallLibrary extends Library{
    CLibrary INSTANCE =
        (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary(("libraryname"), SystemCallLibrary.class);
    int ioctl(int filedes,int request,Object... args);
}
```

What should I replace `"libraryname"` with?

Comment: unless explicitly mentioned in another library, it would be exposed by `libc`, so `Native.loadLibrary("c", LibC.class);`

Comment: consider wrapping the call to ioctl in a function (that you write in c) and calling your function.  the library you would load for this is the library that you create to house your function.

Answer (score 1):

`ioctl` is likely already linked into the JVM itself, so you can pass a library name of `null` or omit the parameter altogether, which means "load from the current process".

[Reference](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.0/javadoc/com/sun/jna/Native.html#loadLibrary(java.lang.Class))